# .NET string contains string[]

Tags: c#

I'm having a small issue putting together this contains statement any help would be awesome.

```
string betaFilePath = @"C:\resultsalpha.txt";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(betaFilePath, FileMode.Open))
using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader((fs)))
{
    while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string betaFileLine = rdr.ReadLine();
        {
            string[] onlythese = {@"apple/",@"aee/",@"www/",@"blk/",@"art/",@"purp/",@"ora/",@"red/",@"brd/",@"biek/",@"biz/"};
            if (betaFileLine.Contains(onlythese))
            {
                File.AppendAllText(@"C:\testtestest.txt", betaFileLine);

            }
        }
    }
```

Error:  Argument '1': cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string'  ->  if (betaFileLine.Contains(onlythese))

Comment: What are you trying to fine - lines containing *any* of those strings, or lines containing *all* of them?

Comment: Don't forget regular expressions :) this could become a Code Golf thread he he.

Answer (score 10):

LINQ to the rescue!

```
if(onlythese.Any(str => betaFileLine.Contains(str)))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yep no sense keeping my duplicate answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass in an array to `String.Contains` - you will need to loop through your string[] and check each, or use LINQ:

```
if(onlythese.Any(a => betaFileLine.Contains(a)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (onlythese.Any(only => betaFileLine.Contains(only))
```

You'll need `using System.Linq;'

Answer (score 2):

If you have Framework 3.5 use LINQ

```
if(onlythese.Any(s => betaFileLine.Contains(s)))
{
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\testtestest.txt", betaFileLine);
}
```

If not you have to loop each string

```
bool match = false;

foreach(String thisString in onlyThese)
{
    if(betaFileLine.Contains(thisString)
    {
        match = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(match)
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\testtestest.txt", betaFileLine);
```

or use regex

```
string onlyThese = @"apple/|aee/|www/|blk/|art/|purp/|ora/|red/|brd/|biek/|biz/";
if (Regex.IsMatch(betaFileLine, onlyThese))
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\testtestest.txt", betaFileLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check for every of them:

```
bool isOK = false;

foreach (string current in onlythese)
  if (betaFileLine.Contains(current))
  {
     isOK = true;
     break;
  }

if (isOK)
{
   File.AppendAllText(@"C:\testtestest.txt", betaFileLine);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string.Contains accept a single string as parameter instead of a string array.

An easy way is to loop through the onlyThese and nest the contains statement inside:

```
string[] onlythese = {@"apple/",@"aee/",@"www/",@"blk/",@"art/",@"purp/",@"ora/",@"red/",@"brd/",@"biek/",@"biz/"};
foreach(string onlyThis in onlythese) 
{
    if (betaFileLine.Contains(onlyThis))
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\testtestest.txt", betaFileLine);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That will append 1 line for EVERY match not ANY match.